# Events in Probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Three messages are being transmitted, each message can be delivered
> correctly or faulty.
>
> We define the following events:
>
> $A_i$ Message i was delivered correctly.
>
> $A_i^c$ Message i was delivered faulty.
>
> We define an event B to indicate that no less than 2 messages were
> delivered correctly. Then B is equal to:  $A_1A_2A_3 \cup A_1A_2 \cup A_1A_3 \cup A_2A_3$

Why is this correct? some events like if all messages were delivered correctly are counted 4 times, I think it should be:

$A_1A_2A_3 \cup A_1A_2A_3^c \cup A_1A_2^cA_3 \cup A_1^cA_2A_3$

Comment: Both are correct. The $\bigcup$ doesn't assume that the sets are disjoint. What could be an error is to split the probability of the first as the sum of the probabilities of the sets being joined. For the second it would be safe to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The union does not double-count anything.  For instance, if you had sets $X=\{1,2\}$ and $Y=\{2,3\}$ then the union is $X\cup Y=\{1,2,3\}$.  So in this sense, a union always contains each element uniquely.

So the event as described above is technically correct.  I would not think it is the best way to write the event, though.  Your description is superior because, with your

$$A_1A_2A_3 \cup A_1A_2A_3^c\cup A_1A_2^cA_3\cup A_1^cA_2A_3 $$

this is a "disjoint union" and therefore much easier to analyze the probability of it.